# jest-jasmine2 env.js unhandled error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I'm getting this cryptic error message when using Jest unit testing to test my code.

> console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:198
>       Unhandled error
>
> console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:199
>       Error
>           at model.wrappedPointCut [as save] (/home/pi/dev/Group_2/node_modules/mongoose/lib/services/model/applyHooks.js:131:29)
>           at /home/pi/dev/Group_2/controllers/Manager.js:80:17
>           at Array.map ()
>           at /home/pi/dev/Group_2/controllers/Manager.js:79:55
>           at 
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7)
>
> console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:198
>       Unhandled error
>
> console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:199

Here's how my test code looks like

```
it.only('Adding a shift entry to DB works', () => {
  expect.assertions(3);
  return m.associateToShifts(["johnDoe"], ["Mondays"]).then(cmdResult => {
    expect(cmdResult.length).toBe(1);
    expect(cmdResult[0].employee.employeeId).toBe("johnd");
    expect(cmdResult[0].shift.shiftTitle).toBe("Mondays");
  }).catch(e => console.log(`Error: Cannot add shift to DB properly. ${e}`));
});
```

Here's how my code in Manager.js looks like on line 70 - 81, which is what jest-jasmine2 is complaining about:

```
var employeeData = Promise.all(employees.map(function(emp) {
      emp.save();
}));
```

`employees` is an array of employee objects based on a mongoose `findOne()` employee query.

The test passes despite having this error shown.

Here are some things I've tried: 1) Update Jest to version 22.0.6 2) Update Node JS to version 9.4.0. None of those attempts have worked.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you forgot to add "return":

```
var employeeData = Promise.all(employees.map(function(emp) {
  return emp.save();
}));
```

Or es6 syntax:

```
let employeeData = Promise.all(employees.map(emp => emp.save()));
```

I had similar problem, when I created some promises, but didn't resolve them.

Comment: I know this is old, but maybe someone will find it useful in the future